# I don't understand why a dismissible is not removed from the widget tree

Tags: flutter

I am trying to understand dismissible widgets and somehow I always end up with the error message that the dismissible is still part of the widget tree. I do understand what the error message is saying but I cannot seem to implement the solution.

Essentially, my problem is that I keep items in a list (via a provider) and onDismissed deletes that entry and rebuilds the state and the index of each Dismissible is an id accessed via an index. I feel like I understand the theory somewhat but one crucial part is missing. If someone could explain what's wrong with the code that would be massively appreciated!

Here is my setup (as simplified as possible)

Main

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => TestDataProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: TestScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

TestScreen widget

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  void removeItem(int id) {
    setState(() => Provider.of<TestDataProvider>(context).removeItem(id));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = Provider.of<TestDataProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: data.items[index],
              child: Dismissible(
                onDismissed: (_) {
                  removeItem(data.items[index].id);
                },
                key: ValueKey(data.items[index].id),
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(data.items[index].name),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text(data.items[index].id.toString()),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

TestDataProvider

```
class TestData with ChangeNotifier {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  TestData(this.id, this.name);
}

class TestDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<TestData> items = [
    TestData(1, 'test'),
    TestData(2, 'hello'),
    TestData(3, 'stuff'),
    TestData(4, 'mine'),
    TestData(5, 'xxx'),
    TestData(6, 'world'),
    TestData(7, 'blue'),
    TestData(8, 'cloud'),
    TestData(9, 'sky'),
  ];

  void removeItem(int id) => items.removeWhere((element) => element.id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Dismissable place a key: UniqueKey(),

Comment: oh, thank you, it does fix the issue. Although, I am confused now: If you can just use a UniqueKey, why would you ever use ValueKey? Is there a specific purpose for it?

Comment: As far as I understood, the UniqueKey() does the trick that ValueKey was supposed to do as unique key, keep tracks of the value. Please do not forget to upvote if you think my answer was usefull.